# Can't connect to wifi again after connecting to mobile network

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My Android is 4.4.

Sometimes when I leave home, my phone changes from connecting to my home wifi to connecting to its mobile network.

When I arrive a place with wifi, e.g. an office or back to my home again, my phone sometimes can't connect to wifi, although sometimes it can. When the problem happens,  I refresh the wifi networks detected by my phone, and disable and enable the phone's wifi, but both doesn't solve the problem.

For my phone to connect to wifi again, my solution is to restart Android.

Is there a solution without restarting Android? For example, can I disable and then enable, and restart wifi connection?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it show WiFi names when you refresh?

Comment: On what device? Samsung? Also, have you downloaded any update before this problem started happening?

Comment: @Vivek   it shows names of all the WIFI networks that it has connected to before, whether they are in range or not, even before I refresh it.

Comment: @Brian Kyocera Hydro Icon. I don't know which update.